# How do I load an image into a List?

Tags: haskell, image-processing

I am using Haskell and attempting to write a function

```
loadImage :: FilePath -> IO [RGBAPixel]
loadImage = ...
type RBGAPixel = (Double, Double, Double, Double)
```

I realize that lists aren't the most efficient way to do this - but I'm just looking to shoehorn something into my existing structure for the moment. What's the easiest way to load an image (.jpg, .bmp, .png, or .tga) into a list in Haskell?

Comment: Use a library, e.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Codec-Image-DevIL (that's my own, I'm sure there are others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [JuicyPixels-repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-repa) this is simple and doesn't require any external (C) libraries:

```
import Codec.Picture.Repa (readImageRGBA, collapseColorChannel)
import Data.Array.Repa as R
import Data.Word

loadImage :: FilePath -> IO [(Word8,Word8,Word8,Word8)]
loadImage fp = do
    img <- either error return =<< readImageRGBA fp
    let arr = collapseColorChannel img
    return $ R.toList arr
```

Or in a more point-free style:

```
loadImage = fmap (R.toList . collapseColorChannel . either error id) . readImageRGBA
```

(Note all this code is typed, not tested.  Feel free to shout with any issues)

Truth in advertising: I maintain JP-repa.

Comment: I think this is what I want - I was using the JuicyPixels library, but I couldn't figure out how to get lists out of the `DynamicImage`, though.

This code gives me the error: `No instance for (Collapsible RGBA e0) arising from a use of 'collapseColorChannel'`.

Comment: Just so you know: I don't see how this will be useful to you.  You don't get any coordinate information - all your rows of pixels are in one indistinguishable list!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I think it will be alright (for now) for loading textures into OpenGL's buffer system. They're just C arrays of color information.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Haskell Image Processing library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip), which in fact uses JuicyPixels for IO, will let you read and write all of the supported formats in a very easy manner:

```
>>> img <- readImageRGB "image.jpg"
>>> :t (toLists img)
(toLists img) :: [[Pixel RGB Double]]
```

Of course you are better off using library's interface to manipulate an image rather than using lists.